# Spring variables not carrying into view

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm very new to Spring and can't seem to figure out what's wrong here. I'm sure it has to be something simple, but anyway:

I was going through the tutorial on [this page](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2010/06/spring-3-mvc-create-hello-world-application-spring-3-mvc.html), and I have nearly identical code. After pulling down the Apache Commons library and the JSTL stuff, I was in business. Everything works, down to it actually using the jsp I specified as the view, but the variable "message" in the controller is not being displayed when the site is rendered. It's not because of the expression language stuff, either, because I'm not getting the ${message} text displaying either. It's just a blank page.

The only reason I know that the jsp is actually being triggered is because I put a title in there that is no where else and it is being used on page display. I also know that the variable is being set in the controller and the action is being called because of a simple sysout that I put in the mapped function.

Thanks for any help!

**EDIT**

Here's the jsp:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" isELIgnored="false"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>om nom JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        ${message}
    </body>
</html>
```

And the controller:

```
package org.me.home.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class SomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/somepage")
    public ModelAndView someAction() {

        String mymsg = "Saying hi!";
        System.out.println(mymsg);
        return new ModelAndView("somepage", "message", mymsg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your jsp and controller?

Comment: After running some debug stuff, I have determined that the message is making it onto the ModelAndView object, but it's not being displayed from the jsp even though it's being called. Maybe I'm missing something with my referencing?

Comment: Looks fine. Do EL expressions such as `${1+1}` evaluate correctly, if you add them to your JSP?

Comment: it does, actually. thanks. didn't think of trying that.

Comment: still having the problem here; i have no idea why the variable `message` isn't carrying through to the jsp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use such a construction:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c"   uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
...
<c:out value="${message}" />
```

And are you sure, that the problem is in displaying? Is page loaded fine, I mean is all other HTML displayed on page, besides "message"?

**EDIT**
Try to use org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView instead of
org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView

Comment: yes, all the other html on the page is displaying. still no dice. Thanks for trying tho.

Comment: Hey, @narloff, I've noticed, that you have used in your work org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView. So it is Portlet. I don't work with Spring MVC Portlets, may be it has some other behaviour. Try to use org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView

Comment: EXCELLENT Catch! please make a separate answer so that I can give you the checkmark!

Answer (score 1):

Your tomcat maybe using the wrong jstl.jar. Under your tomcat lib folder, check if your jstl.jar is the same version you are using with your project.